# How can I make a multiplayer Flash game? What socket libraries are there/how do I make my own?

Tags: c++, python, actionscript-3, flash

I know this question's been asked before, but apparently all the libraries I've found so far have no documentation.

Do you know of any that have proper documentation in C++ or Python (for the server side). Or can you please provide a sample code, where a simple "Hello world" message is sent from Flash to Python/C++/anything and then back, via XMLSocket.

Answer (score 2):

There is a link to a socket server/client written in php/as3 on this site :

http://www.kilometer0.com/blog/code/php-xml-socket-server/

It is pretty simple and handles only a few messages but you can build on it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out ElectroTank Server and SmartFox server.
They are both in wide use. As an added bonus, the authors of ElectroTank released a very good book detailing the ins and outs of making multiplayer flash games.

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/

http://www.electrotank.com/es5.html

http://books.google.com/books/about/ActionScript_for_Multiplayer_Games_and_V.html?id=hDZRa52__F8C

I have the book, and would recommend it as a solid introduction to the topic.